Issue in integrating verlet-list with molecular dynamics code in fortran
(This question is direct copy-paste from Physics SE asked by myself, since I was unaware of Matter Modelling SE.)
I have written the simplest molecular dynamics code with Langevin thermostat in Fortran 95, and it is working fine. Simplest means, no computational time saving is employed yet.
After that I tried to write cell-linked-list and verlet-list separately and integrate them to the previous MD script.
When I run the neighbour-finding codes independently they are working fine. I did very detailed checking by pen-and-paper.
At first I wrote the cell-list code by myself, not following any prescribed algorithm (as in Frenkel and Smit), so that the force-calculation subroutine can be simple, just like in the verlet-list case. But when I integrate it with the MD code ... everything diverges! Even after all boundary conditions applied, particles are running away to mars!
Since verlet-list is a lot simpler, now I tried to integrate this with the MD code. And ... to mars and beyond! Again.
At this point I'm sure that I'm having some technical issue with the code, or, from physics point of view, at most with the boundary condition. I'm applying the following boundary condition for minimum image convention in both the force calculation subroutine and the verlet-list subroutine:
  dx = dx - lx*NINT(dx/lx)
  dy = dy - ly*NINT(dy/ly)

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
